# Set the date on the page (day / month / year)

Tags: php, xml

It is such that I just currently working on getting released time and the real date of the page, the time will come true forward but I lack the right moment is the real date and it should be in Danish

just currently it looks like this;

"Tue, 11 June 2013 07:21:11 GMT"

Want to have it like this;

"Tuesday, June 11, 2013"

The code looks like this;

```
<?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.odin.dk/RSS/RSS.aspx?beredskabsID=d1d94661-0f60-4e67-aeff-304d22199f8a");
 echo "<table id='demo'>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Station</th>";
 echo "<th>Melding</th>";
 echo "<th>Tidspunkt</th>";
 echo "<th>Dato</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 foreach($xml->children() as $child)
 {
   foreach ($child as $c)
   {
     if ($c->getname() == "item")
     {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$c->title."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$c->description."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$c->comments."</tdr>";
       echo "<td>".$c->pubDate."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }
   }
 }
 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Set the date on the page (**day / month / year**)

Hope you can help me to solve this problem.

I only want to get what day it is and what mrd it is and what vein it is?.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [date](http://php.net/date) function, and format it the way you want it.

For example this

```
date("d / M / Y", strtotime('Tue, 11 June 2013 07:21:11 GMT'));
```

Will output

```
11 / Jun / 2013
```

Where

```
d - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
M - A short textual representation of a month, three letters
Y - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
```

Refer PHP's [date](http://php.net/date) for more information.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this when I first was creating an RSS feed. This is how I did it. Good Luck!!

```
    foreach($result as $row) {

    $timethree = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['added_date']);
    $timefinal = date_format($timethree, 'D, d M Y H:i:s');
    $after = $timefinal . ' EST' ; 

    $rssfeed .= "<item>";
    $rssfeed .= "<link><![CDATA[http://areyoujelly.com/blog/".$row['url']."]]></link>";     
    $rssfeed .= "<title><![CDATA[".$row['post_name']."]]></title>";
    $rssfeed .= "<pubDate><![CDATA[".$after."]]></pubDate>";
    $rssfeed .= "<dc:creator><![CDATA[".$row['full_name']."]]></dc:creator>";
    $rssfeed .= "<description><![CDATA[".$row['post_desc']."]]></description>";
    $rssfeed .= "<guid isPermaLink='true'><![CDATA[http://areyoujelly.com/blog/".$row['url']."]]></guid>";
    $rssfeed .= "";


    $rssfeed .= "</item>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime::createFromFormat() ;)
http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d F Y H:i:s e', 'Tue, 11 June 2013 07:21:11 GMT');
echo $date->format('l, F j, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and for the dte format you please refer to manual

```
$this->load->helper('date');
$date=gmdate("Y-M-d");
```